# Using a for-loop to access specific key/value pairs from JSON data

Tags: python, json

I am attempting to pull the key/value pairs from two specific items in JSON data

The data looks like this:

```
[{"voc": "UAT",
"concepts":[{"prefLabel":"Solar system",
    "uri":"http://astrothesaurus.org/uat/1528", "score":"15" },
    {"prefLabel":"X-ray astronomy",
    "uri":"http://astrothesaurus.org/uat/1810", "score":"9" },
    {"prefLabel":"Gamma-ray astronomy",
    "uri":"http://astrothesaurus.org/uat/628", "score":"9" }
]}]
```

I am only trying to retrieve the prefLabel and score using a for-loop that will save them to a tuple to later be appended to my currently empty data list.

This is my current loop but it returns a 'wrong type' error:

```
for concepts in voc_list:
    for prefLabel, score in concepts.items():
        data_tuple = (prefLabel, score)
        data.append(data_tuple)`
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could search the list of dictionaries, and append to the `data` list when the `key` matches the desired string:

```
for d in voc_list[0]['concepts']:
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == 'prefLabel':
            data.append((k, v))
```

Comment: Thank you for this, when I try it, it returns "Wrong type <class 'str'> when expected number". None of my values are numbers so I don't see any work around solution.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It seems like I can't reproduce your JSON data as you have it. This is how I am running it. Feel free to change it so I can see how you are getting that error. https://repl.it/@downshift/JitteryInnocentDemoware